# Boot hangs, low graphics error and login-failure

Tags: boot, xorg, login

I am new to Ubuntu and using 12.10. This appears when I start my system:

```
 speech-dispatcher disabled :edit/etc/default/speech-dispatcher
 saned disabled: edit/etc/default/saned
  * Checking battery state OK
```

After this nothing happens. Checking battery state doesn't come to an end and I have to try to reboot the system again and again until tty1 window appears which is then followed by a low graphics mode error.

I am using the Intel graphics card; the dedicated AMD Radeon 7700 is disabled. I don't want to use the AMD one but want to have a smooth operation with the Intel one. I have tried re installing the X.org drivers for Intel but still have the error of low graphics. I am not sure whether the two problems are related to each other or not.

Today I am facing a new problem. I can't login into my original user account. Whenever I enter the password the screen blinks and prompts for the password again. So I have to login as a different user. But the original problem of "saned disabled" still exists. When when I try Ctrl+Alt+F1 and `startX` I get the following error.

```
Fatal server error.
No screens found. 
(EE). 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation Support for help.
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
xnit: giving up.
xnit: unable to connect to X server : Connection refused.
xnit: server error. 
xnit: timeout in locking authority file /home/user name/.Xauthority`.
```

Then I have no options but to try rebooting the system again and again until I get to login in Graphical Mode where I can't login as the original user.

Answer (score 1):

The initial messages you see are just the output of the various packages running below what you (normally) see as the graphical interface. I recently had the same login loop problem; it was caused by an overly-specific autogenerated xorg.conf file (found in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`).

Try re-generating your Xorg.conf file using

```
sudo Xorg -configure
```

Alternatively, you could even rename your existing xorg file and reboot to make the X server automatically detect the environment. Without the configuration file, it should automatically load the Intel integrated drivers and use your monitor's native resolution.